# Как изменить цвет Меню в Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, menu

Возможно ли изменить цвет меню в Tkinter? То есть в моём примере меню выглядит стандартно(код и скрин ниже), но хотелось бы изменить его под стилистику VS Code(см. скрин). Как это можно сделать?

### Код

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

menu = tk.Menu(root)
root.config(menu = menu)

menu.add_cascade(label='Привет')

root.mainloop()
```

### Скрины

Меню моего примера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Меню VS Code:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
menu = tk.Menu(root, bg="#505050")
```

Попробуйте таким образом.

Comment: К сожалению, это работает только со вложенным меню(

Comment: @DGDays, здесь неплохое решение, которое можно доработать - (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836000/can-i-change-the-title-bar-in-tkinter)

Comment: Задумка интересная, но мне хотелось бы только фон и зменить, а не полностью `title` переписать

Comment: @DGDays, подругому это сделать невозможно. Только переписав полностью.

Comment: Жаль( Буду тогда рыться в tcl файлах, может что-то найду

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте написать `root.config(bg='Some color')`. В кавычках напишите цвет:
hex или название.

Comment: Не работает( Меняет только задний фон самого окна

Answer (score -1):

```
root.iconbitmap('some-path') # Путь к иконке
root.title('Файл  Правка  Выделение  Вид  Переход  Выполнить  Терминал  Справка') # Фейковые кнопочки :D
root.config(bg='#404040') # Можно окрасить окно, но, к сожалению, не меню (хотя, возможно у вас будет по-другому)
```

Возможно, это вам поможет.

Comment: Это конечно хорошо, но не то что хотелось бы(